# swiftでスクロールビュー

Tags: swift

現在、swiftで簡単なスクロービュー(スライドすると、次の写真にすすむ)を作っています。画像表示はできたのですが、画像が画面いっぱいに伸びきった状態でアスペクト比を整えたきれいな表示ができません。

`scrollView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit`
を挿入しているのですが、どこがいけないのでしょうか？

ご教授お願いしたします。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var pageImagesArr = ["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg"];

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let width = self.view.frame.maxX, height = self.view.frame.maxY
        let pageSize = self.pageImagesArr.count;

        //ScrollViewの作成
        scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: self.view.frame)
        scrollView.pagingEnabled = true
        scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,width,height);
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGFloat(pageSize) * width, 0)
        __scrollView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit__

        //各ページの作成
        for var i = 0; i < pageSize; i++ {
            let img:UIImage = UIImage(named:self.pageImagesArr[i])!;
            let iv:UIImageView = UIImageView(image:img);
            iv.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(i) * width, 0, width, height);
            scrollView.addSubview(iv)
        }
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

手元で確認できなくて申し訳ないのですが、
UIImageViewにAspectFitを設定してみたらどうですか？

```
//各ページの作成
for var i = 0; i < pageSize; i++ {
    let img:UIImage = UIImage(named:self.pageImagesArr[i])!;
    let iv:UIImageView = UIImageView(image:img);
    // 画像のアスペクト比を保持する
    iv.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    iv.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(i) * width, 0, width, height);
    scrollView.addSubview(iv)
}
```

Comment: できました！！
なぜ、scrollViewではできなかったのでしょうか？

Comment: @Yuiki 画像(UIImage)の親がUIImageViewだからですね。デフォルトだとUIImageViewに貼り付けた時点で画像が引き伸ばされているはずです。